# Oracle - delete statement slow in small table

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-delete

i have the following delete statement inside a procedure:

```
   delete t_excuse 
   where EMP_NO = AL_EMPNO 
   AND TO_CHAR(EXCUSE_DATE,'yyyymmdd') BETWEEN LS_STARTDATE_G AND LS_ENDDATE_G;
```

which is slow around 10 secs.

but when i add any select with same where clause then execute the delete, it is fast.

```
select count(*) 
into v_avariable from t_excuse 
      where EMP_NO = AL_EMPNO 
        AND TO_CHAR(EXCUSE_DATE,'yyyymmdd') BETWEEN LS_STARTDATE_G AND LS_ENDDATE_G; 

delete t_excuse 
      where EMP_NO = AL_EMPNO 
        AND TO_CHAR(EXCUSE_DATE,'yyyymmdd') BETWEEN LS_STARTDATE_G AND LS_ENDDATE_G;
```

Comment: Are there any trigger defined on t_excuse? Any indexes? Indexes would be updated on delete, and any delete triggers executed - both does not happen with the select statement, hence this might be an explanation for the difference in performance.

Comment: no triggers but default indexes on pk columns

Comment: Check for indexes on all your foreign keys in your whole data model. If any are missing, create them.

Comment: If this is truly a small table it's possible that performing the SELECT first causes the entire table to be read into memory, which makes the following DELETE much faster. It would be easier to offer advice if you'd edit your question and include the definition of table `T_EXCUSE`, including all indexes defined and all constraints (primary, unique, foreign key, not null, etc). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> TO_CHAR(EXCUSE_DATE,'yyyymmdd') BETWEEN LS_STARTDATE_G AND
>   LS_ENDDATE_G

Why are you comparing `literal` with `date`? Avoid `implicit conversion`. If the data type of the columns is `DATE`, then simply use the date columns, `TO_CHAR` is for display in the format you desire, `TO_DATE` is for operations.

```
delete t_excuse 
   where EMP_NO = AL_EMPNO 
   AND EXCUSE_DATE BETWEEN to_date(LS_STARTDATE_G,'yyyymmdd') 
                       AND to_date(LS_ENDDATE_G,'yyyymmdd');
```

If you have an index on `EXCUSE_DATE` column, then now Oracle will use the `index`. Check the explain plan with the new query.

**EDIT** If you really want to get rid off the time portion, use `TRUNC`. But, that would suppress `INDEX` usage. You need to create a `function-based` index as `TRUNC(EXCUSE_DATE)`.

Comment: since there are time part also in date i am converting the column to to_char to eliminate the time part

Comment: then use `TRUNC` and create a `function-based index` as `TRUNC(EXCUSE_DATE)`.

Comment: earlier tried function-based index as to_char(excuse_date,'yyyymmdd') will it serve same

Comment: Use the query I gave, create `function-based index TRUNC(EXCUSE_DATE)` and in the query put `trunc(excuse_date)`